# Isolate inner form

Tags: angular

Is it possible to have a component with a form on it that can be used in another form where its functionality does not impact on the outer form?

I have a component that's used for resetting a password and consists of a form with some password inputs. It's reused in a few places in the application, one of which is on the page where users can edit their profile, which is also a form. In this case, when someone tries to change their password in the component, the outer form for the user profile is submitted. Ideally I want to only submit the password form if the user is in the password component, and only submit the user profile form if the user hits submit on the user profile form.

Given that nested forms are not valid HTML, do I need to reconsider how I'm setting this up and make sure that no components with forms are placed in forms?

Comment: Keep in mind that you don't actually need a form tag to encapsulate form inputs. You could easily have a separate FormGroup instance within another component to isolate that functionality without affecting the outer component.

Comment: Leaving off the form tag seems to work if I also change the way the password (inner) form is submitted. Rather than binding the action to the submit event, I'm binding to the click event on the change password button and changing its type to `button` rather than `submit`. But if a user presses enter after entering data on the inner component the outer form is still submitted. Is there a way to prevent that given that the inner component doesn't know about the outer form, or even if there is one?

Comment: Yes. You'll also need to change the structure of the outer form as well to not include the form tag, or change the event handling. It's not the most elegant solution to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't semantically great, but it works. Thanks for the pointer in the right direction Brandon. The form tag from inner form (in the nested component) needs to be removed. It can't be submitted with the `submit` event anymore so we need another way of doing it.

The inner forms submit button should be changed to `type="button"` to make sure it doesn't trigger any submit events, and the action should now be bound to the click event instead. To make it behave in the same way as a proper form we also need to be able to 'submit' it on pressing enter. This can be done by binding to the keydown event.

```
<input type="password" (keydown)="onKeyDown($event)" #passwordInput>
<button type="button" (click)="onResetPassword()">Reset</button>
```

the `onKeyDown` function in the inner component checks if the enter button was pressed. If it was, it performs the action that the submit would normally do. It also needs to prevent the default action which stops the outer form from being submitted. If a different key was pressed, nothing special needs to happen.

```
onKeyDown (event: KeyboardEvent) {
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
    this.onResetPassword() // This used to be bound to submit.
    event.preventDefault()
  }
}
```

This inner component is then safe to used in other components and it doesn't matter if it's used in forms or not.